# Infusionsoft retrieve all custom fields value for specific contact

Tags: php, api, infusionsoft

I've been searching for this solution but haven't found one! I'm using [Novak solution's Infusionsoft API](https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk).

What I'm trying to do is to get value of a custom field for specific contact. Lets say, I've a custom fields named `_myCustomField` with Yes/No value. I've 200 contacts in my list but only 15 contact has value 'Yes' for `_myCustomField`. Lets say I've another custom field `_myCustomField2`. If I run following query:

```
$contacts = Infusionsoft_DataService::query( new Infusionsoft_Contact(), array('_myCustomField' => '1') );
```

I get an array of 15 records, BUT if I print `$contacts` array then I don't see `_myCustomField` or `_myCustomField2` there.

So, how do I get value for those two custom field inside my loop? Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you just don't output information correctly, as you say you get array of records, but cannot 'print' it. Please provide your code that shows the issue exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the query method is only the filter and does not tell Infusionsoft that you also want to return any custom fields.

You will want to add the custom fields first:

```
$contact = new Infusionsoft_Contact();

$contact->addCustomField('_myCustomField');
$contact->addCustomField('_myCustomField2');

$contacts = Infusionsoft_DataService::query( $contact, array('_myCustomField' => '1') );
```

Comment: what library are you using for this? Can you send me the link, please? Thanks! :)